# configure virtual host on tomcat

Tags: tomcat, virtualhost

I am able to run my application on tomcat with url as `http://localhost:8080/pfaf/test.html`.

In my application I am accessing the styles as /styles/abc.css. When opening the application I found in console that it is looking the css at `http://localhost:8080/styles`. where as when this application is running in WAS(it has a virtual host) it works great.

So can someone please help me in creating a virtual host on tomcat so that URL becomes as `http://pfaf.localhost:8080/test.html`

Thanks in advance,

-Ritesh

Answer (score 4):

In most versions of Tomcat, including Tomcat6 and Tomcat7, you add virtual hosts by adding a 
**Host** element to the **Engine** element in the server.xml file

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html

Example:

```
   <Host name="pfaf.localhost" appBase="pfaf_webapps"   
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"/>
```

To deploy a war file into this new virtual host, place it into **$CATALINA_HOME/pfaf_webapps**.